# C Program, User input into a single array

Tags: c, arrays, user-interface

I'm trying to use three integers that are inputted by a user in a single line into an array using CodeBlocks. But i don't really know how to go about this. Can anyone help me?

Thanks!

```
main()
{

    int arr[3];
    int onenum;
    int twonum;
    int threenum;
    printf("Enter an Input: ");
    scanf("%d %d %d",&onenum,&twonum,&threenum);
    printf("Your input is: %d %d %d \n",onenum,twonum,threenum); 
    int arr [onenum, twonum, threenum];

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you please indent this?

Comment: `for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) scanf("%d", &arr[i]);`

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
int i;
int arr[3];
printf("Enter numbers");
for(i=0;i<3;i++){
    scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
}
```

This will store the 3 numbers entered by user in array arr.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
void main() 
{

int arr[3];
int i;

printf("Enter an Input: ");

for(i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
{
    scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
}


printf("Your input is: ");
for(i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
{
    printf("%d ", arr[i]);
}
printf("\n");

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's use a loop from which runs from i=0 to i=2 because you have to add 3 numbers in array.

```
void main()
{

    int arry[3],i=0;
    printf("enter numbers");
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&arry[i]); 
    }
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        printf("%d \n",arry[i]); 
    }

}
```

Array is a collection of data.
For beginning you can think a array with different index as a different variable of same data type means arry[0] and arry[1] in this example as different variables of same data type integer.It will help you for beginning with array but **keep in mind** that **arry** is the only one variable the index inside capital bracket tells the variable where to look.